# What would the BIOS update for 100 series chipsets for kaby lake actually do?

Tags: intel, bios, chipset

I was reading that in order for kaby lake to be supported on 100 series chipsets, a BIOS update is required.

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-3371914/kaby-lake-chipsets.html

Wikichip also displays that Sunrise Point is still supported but with a BIOS update : https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/kaby_lake

What specifically would this BIOS update do to allow for a kaby lake CPU to be supported. Or indeed in the general case, what would a BIOS update do specifically to make a chipset compatible with the CPU.

I have heard BIOS updates update microcode in the MSROM but that's probably not the only thing. There are many tutorials on google about *how* to update the BIOS but not many about *what it actually does*.

Comment: Maybe something about how it sets up the onboard GPU (which did change from SKL), or maybe things about configuring power-management.

Comment: I have a new suggestion. Perhaps the device and function numbers of the components on die have changed on kaby Lake and the bios needs to alter its way of configuring